# how to set IDENTITY_INSERT as ON?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

in the first I ask the admin to remove this post: 
'how-can-i-make-a-primary-key-as-autoincrement-in-vb-net-2008/959787#959787'
because I am facing a problem with comment and when I try to add comment the error message is apper: "commenting requires 50 reputation -- see faq" !

Here just I want to ask about IDENTITY_INSERT, how can I set it as ON in vb.net 2008
this error occur: http://www.rofof.com/img2/6amojc6.gif

I am so sorry for this problems which I cause it.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like your Linq to SQL classes are out of sync with your database. You need to update them. If you are using the built-in visual studio designer, delete the table from your DBML and then add it again.

The attributes for the primary key columns should have attributes that look like this:

```
[Column(Storage="_TeacherID", 
 AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, 
 DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", 
 IsPrimaryKey=true, 
 IsDbGenerated=true)]
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I needed, using Visual Studio :)

Answer (score 1):

In case it is what you want to do, You must also include the table name.

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON`

Answer (score 0):

Well using,

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON
```

but it has to be done with the same connection (without closing the connection) where you perform your query.

By the way, are you sure you want to insert a value in identity column? Maybe your linq to sql mapping is not up to date. If that is the situation, you can

- drop the table from the model and reallocate it, or
- select in your linq to sql model the field wich is identity and set it's properties as

  IsDBGenerated = True

  AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert